# Installing a Ruby Gem on a Dockerized Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I want to install awesome_print in my dockerized ruby application. Running

```
docker-compose run application_name gem install awesome_print
```

says "Successfully installed awesome_print-1.8.0," however, it does not appear in my Gemfile even after running

```
docker-compose run application_name bundle install
```

How can I install awesome_print in my dockerized application?

Comment: you can add a `CMD` to your docker file which rum the script that install that gem

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: The `Gemfile` is a file listing dependencies for `bundler`. It is created and maintained by a person and is not impacted by `gem` commands.

Answer (score 2):

The RubyGems `gem` command is actually a much older package manager that predates bundler.

Running `gem install foo` just installs the gem to your local repository (a folder somewhere). It does not add the gem to your Gemfile and it does not perform the dependency tree resolution that Bundler does to ensure that your gems are actually compatible.

Bundler is built on top of `gem`. To install gems with bundler (which is what you pretty much always want to do) you add the gem to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

```
gem 'awesome_print', '~> 1.8'
```

Bundler also has a [`bundle add`](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-add.1.html) command which will add a gem to the Gemfile and install your bundle, for example:

```
bundle add awesome_print --version "~> 1.8"
```